# "TargetPlatform.macOS is not yet supported by the maps plugin" error in FlutterFlow

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutterflow

On Flutterflow when I add the Google Maps Widget on a page I get this error. I followed all the steps found in the FlutterFlow Docs: I enabled the Maps API on the Google Developer Console and added the keys to FlutterFlow.
Can someone please help me?

I tried regenerating new keys and double checked that I put the keys in the right place.